# sql - how to retrieve rows belongs to sub catergories

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am really stuck here and need some help. In following table, how can retrieve top two a quantity record of each country?

```
create table receivers(
country varchar(10) not null,
date datetime not null,
quantity integer not null
);

insert into receivers values ("china", "2000-01-01", 100);
insert into receivers values ("japan", "2000-01-01", 900);
insert into receivers values ("usa", "2000-01-01", 345);
insert into receivers values ("usa", "2000-01-01", 234);
insert into receivers values ("usa", "2000-01-01", 56);
insert into receivers values ("usa", "2000-01-01", 12);
insert into receivers values ("china", "2000-01-01", 300);
insert into receivers values ("china", "2000-01-01", 10);
insert into receivers values ("china", "2000-01-01", 1000);
```

I am using mysql, postgresql

Comment: post the output also

Comment: Tag the dbms used! (Your SQL is a bit product specific.)

Comment: Please specify SQL engine. They all have own implementation of `SELECT TOP n ... ORDER BY quantity DESC`

Answer (score 4):

Try this-

```
SELECT country, quantity FROM (SELECT country, quantity, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY country
                           ORDER BY quantity DESC) as rnum FROM receivers) WHERE rnum<3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a window function:

```
select country, date, quantity
from (
  select country, date, quantity, 
         dense_rank() over (partition by country order by quantity desc) as rnk
  from receivers
) t
where rnk <= 2;
```

The above is standard ANSI SQL and works on all DBMS that support [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/slides)